# Changing Bootstrap Nav menu to hover and retaining parent link

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've read quite a few threads here about changing bootstrap menu dropdown to onhover action vs. onclick.

I too am interested in this and most of what I've tried seems to work, however, I've lost the capability to click on the parent link in the menu. Furthermore, when I click on the parent link (trying to visit the page) the dropdown menu stays open.

I've used the following CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
  /* Make Navigation Toggle on Desktop Hover */
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
      display: block;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
   .navbar-header {
       float: none;
   }
   .navbar-toggle {
       display: block;
   }
   .navbar-collapse {
       border-top: 1px solid transparent;
       box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
   }
   .navbar-collapse.collapse {
       display: none!important;
   }
   .navbar-nav {
       float: none!important;
       margin: 7.5px -15px;
   }
   .navbar-nav>li {
       float: none;
   }
   .navbar-nav>li>a {
       padding-top: 10px;
       padding-bottom: 10px;
   }
   .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
       display: block!important;
   }
   .collapsing {
       overflow: hidden!important;
   }
}
```

I've also found the following script which should make the parent nav link clickable:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
         var location = $(this).attr('href');
         window.location.href = location;
         return false;
});
```

This was all pieced together from various threads/sources I found here. Everything works, BUT the parent link doesn't not click through to the page, AND when clicking the parent link, the dropdown menu stays open.

Does anyone have an idea of how to make this work??

Here is the HTML navigation:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
    <ul id="top-nav" class="nav navbar-nav"><li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://saiinfocomm.borellidesigns.com/" class="external">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://saiinfocomm.borellidesigns.com/about-us/" class="external">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://saiinfocomm.borellidesigns.com/our-services/" class="external">Services</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-38" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children dropdown"><a href="http://saiinfocomm.borellidesigns.com/practices/" class="external">Practices</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://saiinfocomm.borellidesigns.com/information-technology/" class="external">Information Technology</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-67" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://saiinfocomm.borellidesigns.com/telecommunications/" class="external">Telecommunications</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://saiinfocomm.borellidesigns.com/electronics-industry/" class="external">Electronics Industry</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-144 current_page_item active "><a href="http://saiinfocomm.borellidesigns.com/verticals/" class="external">Verticals</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://saiinfocomm.borellidesigns.com/contact-us/" class="external">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-39" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.strategicanalysis.com" class="external">SAI Corporate</a></li>
    </ul>                       
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your relevant HTML.

Comment: @josh - editing the original message to include HTML

Comment: it would be helpful if you could create a JS.Fiddle duplicating the issue or a link to a live version of your site. The code you posted only shows a small piece of whats going on.

Comment: @crazymatt The link to development site is: [http://saiinfocomm.borellidesigns.com] if you click/hover on any one of the parent links, on desktop you will see the issue happening

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute "disabled" to the anchor tag for the parent list item:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle disabled" href="http://saiinfocomm.borellidesigns.com/practices/">Practices<b class="caret"></b></a>
```